# How to polygonize raster to shapely polygons

Tags: python-2.7, shapely, polygonize

I am seeking an open-source python solution to convert raster to polygon (no ArcPy).

I did know the GDAL function to convert raster to polygon, and here is the manual: http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#polygonize-a-raster-band

Nevertheless, I expect that the output can be shapely polygons or any object, temporarily in memory, not saved as a file. Is there any package or code to handle this issue?

If the raster has been processed in a numpy array, the approach is listed below.

Comment: I am not sure if one mix those two packages. Are you aware of mutual incompatibilites between rasterio and gdal? > **Mutual Incompatibilities** Rasterio and GDAL’s bindings can contend for global GDAL objects. Unless you have deep knowledge about both packages, choose exactly one of `import osgeo.gdal` or import `rasterio` [see here](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/switch.html)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) of Sean Gillies. It can be easily combined with [Fiona](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (read and write shapefiles) and [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) of the same author.

In the script [rasterio_polygonize.py](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/fb93a6425c17f25141ad308cee7263d0c491a0a9/examples/rasterio_polygonize.py)
 the beginning is

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.features import shapes
mask = None
with rasterio.Env():
    with rasterio.open('a_raster') as src:
        image = src.read(1) # first band
        results = (
        {'properties': {'raster_val': v}, 'geometry': s}
        for i, (s, v) 
        in enumerate(
            shapes(image, mask=mask, transform=src.transform)))
```

The result is a generator of GeoJSON features

```
 geoms = list(results)
 # first feature
 print geoms[0]
 {'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(202086.577, 90534.3504440678), (202086.577, 90498.96207), (202121.96537406777, 90498.96207), (202121.96537406777, 90534.3504440678), (202086.577, 90534.3504440678)]]}, 'properties': {'raster_val': 170.52000427246094}}
```

That you can transform into shapely geometries

```
from shapely.geometry import shape
print shape(geoms[0]['geometry'])
POLYGON ((202086.577 90534.35044406779, 202086.577 90498.96206999999, 202121.9653740678 90498.96206999999, 202121.9653740678 90534.35044406779, 202086.577 90534.35044406779))
```

Create geopandas Dataframe and enable easy to use functionalities of spatial join, plotting, save as geojson, ESRI shapefile etc.

```
geoms = list(results)
import geopandas as gp
gpd_polygonized_raster  = gp.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geoms)
```

Comment: if the raster has been processed as a numpy array, is there any way to convert a numpy array as polygons? Thanks!

Comment: In theory, yes-

Comment: The mask variable and parameter in your example seems unnecessary. I would however recommend to add `if value > src.nodata` to the list comprehension to make use of the source's nodata value and discard any shapes that correspond to it. Not sure what would happen if there is no nodata vaue though. :o)

Comment: meanwhile they changed rasterio.drivers to rasterio.Env and src.affine to src.transform

Comment: When I tried this I get a polygon with a crs of None. So I tried setting the crs to the original image's but then it shows it in the completely wrong place. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Here is my implementation.

```
from osgeo import ogr, gdal, osr
from osgeo.gdalnumeric import *  
from osgeo.gdalconst import * 
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape
import rasterio.features

#segimg=glob.glob('Poly.tif')[0]
#src_ds = gdal.Open(segimg, GA_ReadOnly )
#srcband=src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
#myarray=srcband.ReadAsArray() 
#these lines use gdal to import an image. 'myarray' can be any numpy array

mypoly=[]
for vec in rasterio.features.shapes(myarray):
    mypoly.append(shape(vec))
```

The way to install rasterio is by 'conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/ioos rasterio', if there is an installation issue.

Comment: The result of rasterio is directly a numpy array, therefore you don't need `myarray=srcband.ReadAsArray() #or any array`

Comment: @gene I revised the note. This line (myarray=srcband.ReadAsArray()) uses gdal to import the image.

Comment: import the image as a numpy array and rasterio import directly the image as a numpy array

Comment: This worked for me although I had to index vec because it was being returned as a tuple. shape(vec[0])

Answer (score 3):

```
# PYTHON 3

import rasterio.features
from shapely.geometry import shape

# Mask is a numpy array binary mask loaded however needed
maskShape = rasterio.features.shapes(mask.astype('uint8'))
mypoly=[]
for vec in maskShape:
    mypoly.append(vec[0])
print(mypoly)
```

This is what worked for me.

Comment: Is it also possible to change the input data from an numpy array to an GeoTIF (dataset = rasterio.open('raster_data.tif'). How would you change the parameters from rasterio.features.shapes()?

Comment: You can always just get the numpy array directly from the GeoTIF: n_array = yourgeotif.read(1), although you would miss the geospatial info which you may have to provide by yourself transform = yourgeotif.transform

Comment: I am trying soph's task too, and my already uint8 binary raster is producing a maskShape that seems not to be iterable in the line for vec in maskShape:  Error at that line is 'DatasetReader' object has no attribute 'dtype.'  type(maskShape) is generator.

Comment: the resulting vectors in mypoly are in local coordinates (row, col); to transform them to geographic coordinates, you can use the transform of the raster and the function  rasterio.transform.xy()

Answer (score 0):

Incase of pixels with high variability, convert the arrays to integer type. Helps to save on computation time.

```
with rio.Env():
with rio.open(input_file_path) as depth_image:
    depth_array=depth_image.read(1).astype(int)
```