# Iterating over a raster using rasterio, and then saving to a shapefile

Tags: python, raster, rasterio

I'm trying to create a script to polygonalize a raster using rasterio. I want to only polygonalize pixel values that are not null.

[From this SO answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187877/how-to-polygonize-raster-to-shapely-polygons), I derived this function:

```
def create_geometry(raster_input):
"""
Creates a shapely polygon from a raster image
:param raster_input: raster path
:return: shapely geometry
"""
mask = None
results = None
pixels = []

# with rasterio.drivers():
with rasterio.open(raster_input) as src:
    image = src.read(1)  # first band
    results = (
        {'properties': {'raster_val': v}, 'geometry': s}
        for i, (s, v)
        in enumerate(
        shapes(image, mask=mask, transform=src.affine)))
return results
```

That function is called by this function, which then saves to shapefile using the polygonalize_geometry() function:

```
def shape_builder(raster_input, output_path):
"Builds a polygon out of the pixel polygons"

# polygons = []
polygons = create_geometry(raster_input)

for polygon in polygons:
    polygon = shape(polygon[0]['geometry'])
    print(polygon)
    polygonalize_geometry(polygon, output_path)
```

I then convert it into shapely geometry, and then write a shapefile. However, the shapefile only contains one feature that encompasses one pixel (shown below). I believe that it is only operating on the first pixel it finds. The SO answer I linked above says that the function is a generator, but I haven't ever been able to figure out how to use them. I'm pretty sure that's the issue.

[image]

So the script is *somewhat* working.

[The entire script is here.](https://github.com/minorsecond/PolygonalizeRaster/blob/master/polygonalizeRaster.py)

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: "that the function is a generator " :`list(generator)` is a list and you can browse the generator with `for i in generator:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ross, I think the only thing that is wrong is that you're re-opening the shapefile in 'w' mode in `polygonalize_geometry()` for every shape. 'w' doesn't mean "append to shapefile", it means "overwrite shapefile". Try Python's `open()` in 'w' mode, for example, `fiona.open()` has exactly the same behavior. Change your program so that the output vector collection is opened only once and you'll be back on track.