# Extracting shapely polygons from .png file?

Tags: python, raster, geometry

I have a .png file coming from a WMS service (WFS is not available). It only  contains "straight" lines and I would like to extract the geometries (shapely polygons) of the connected components of objects in the image.

[image]

I tried some basic solutions like using `shapes` from `rasterio.features` but the results were bad. There are 35 polygons in this image (if you pad the borders) and I either got thousands or a dozen. The polygons do not need to be perfectly aligned with the lines but I couldn't get even close to a working solution.

I consulted a solution to a similar problem ([How to polygonize raster to shapely polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187877/how-to-polygonize-raster-to-shapely-polygons)) but it did not work well here.

I also tried finding contours and lines using various OpenCV methods but I still wasn't satisfied with the outcome. It seems like a pretty straightforward task but I can't find any working solution.

Comment: When using `rasterio.features` did you try vectorizing the white pixels as opposed to the blue ones?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.