# Converting GeoJSON to a raster image using rasterio

Tags: python, geojson, geotiff-tiff, rasterio

My geospatial data knowledge is limited. I am hoping for advice as to how I can convert the full GeoJSON geometry into a tif image using `rasterio`.

I have tried using `gdal_rasterize` to no avail. Not all the geometry was rasterized even after I set the `-at` (ALL_TOUCHED) parameter.

Comment: Not the final solution but take a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187877/how-to-polygonize-raster-to-shapely-polygons for common wording of the problem.

Comment: The problem is not the same - it is similar. I have edited the question for clarification purposes.

Comment: I already had the geometry as a `shapely` object and converted it to GeoJSON. I need to rasterize all the lat/lon coordinates in that GeoJSON.