# Polygonize RGB mage considering all 3 bands simultaneously

Tags: python, geojson, rasterio, python-3, polygonize

I'm using the [rasterio.features.shapes](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.features.html#rasterio.features.shapes) method to generate GeoJSON information from a PNG file. [This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187877/how-to-polygonize-raster-to-shapely-polygons?newreg=7ce3dfdbe4c8401c9c99129983d1b752) shows what I'm trying to do, except I need to analyze the RGB bands simultaneously otherwise the polygons won't be correct. I'm circumventing this by converting first the triplet of 3 int8 to a single 32bit integer using the bitshift operator, but I feel I'm missing the obvious solution to combine the 3 bands together in some way. I'm also using PIL and numpy to process the image.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from rasterio.features import shapes

def find_polygons():
    im = Image.open(f"myimage.png")
    arr = np.array(im)
    out = np.vectorize(rgb_to_int32, otypes=[np.int32])(*np.rollaxis(arr, 2, 0))
    for i, (s, v) in enumerate(shapes(out)):
        r, g, b = int32_to_rgb(v)
    print(i)


def rgb_to_int32(r, g, b):
    return (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b


def int32_to_rgb(n):
    n = int(n)
    return n >> 16 & 0xFF, n >> 8 & 0xFF, n & 0xFF
```

This produces the desired result, but I feel like I'm missing the obvious solution. Any tips in the right direction?

For reference, this is the image I'm trying to extract data from:[image: eu4 world map]