# Convert Numpy array to shapefile

Tags: python, raster, shapefile

I read in a raster and turned it into a binary image (land/water mask) of 0's (water) and 255's (land). I've named this array `src_landCoverArray`.

I want to output this array as a shapefile with water as polygons and land as empty space.

I've tried using `rasterio.features.shapes()` described here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898113/python-boolean-array-to-polygon) but it produced a shapefile with the wrong extent. My code:

```
import shapely.geometry
myShapes = rasterio.features.shapes(src_landCoverArray)
polygons = [shapely.geometry.Polygon(shape[0]["coordinates"][0]) for shape in myShapes if shape[1] == 0]
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
my_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(crs=crs, geometry=polygons)
my_gdf.to_file("Water_Poly2.shp", driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

I've tried using a similar method with `rasterio` described here ([How to polygonize raster to shapely polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187877/how-to-polygonize-raster-to-shapely-polygons/187889#187889)) but failed again with the location/extent being incorrect. My code:

```
mypoly = []

for vec in rasterio.features.shapes(src_landCoverArray):
    mypoly.append(shape(vec[0]))
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
my_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(crs=crs, geometry=mypoly)
my_gdf.to_file("Water_Poly_mypoly.shp", driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

I feel that I'm close to success if I could figure out the issue of extent/location being wrong. Has anyone tackled a problem similar to this?

Comment: can you say more about what goes wrong in each case and what you expected it to produce instead

Comment: @IanTurton Yes. Ideally I'd like to produce a Polygon shapefile that has water (0's) as polygons and land (255's) as empty space. The first attempt I listed produces a .shp file, but when I load it in QGIS it's nowhere near where it should be; the CRS is correct but the extent is wrong. The same thing happens with my second attempt. Clearly I'm not defining the extent/pixel size but I'm lost on how to incorporate that into this script.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have experienced this issue before. The key detail is that `rasterio.features.shapes` needs to know about the "transform" of the raster dataset. (The "transform" is how it maps the pixels in the array to the actual coordinates.)

The dataset has a `.transform` property that you can pass to `rasterio.features.shapes`, as in [this example](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/features.html#extracting-shapes-of-raster-features) from the rasterio documentation (where `src` is the dataset):

```
shapes = features.shapes(blue, mask=mask, transform=src.transform)
```

I don't think I see the name of your dataset variable in your post, so I can't suggest the exact code you need.

Comment: I've seen that `.transform` function before, that makes perfect logical sense. I tried what you suggested, `src_Transform = src_rasterio.transform
src_Shapes = rasterio.features.shapes(src_landCoverArray, transform=src_Transform)` and got a shapely generator object. But when I go to turn that into a geodataframe and then save it as a shapefile it failed with "TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'". Maybe I don't need to go that extra step of using a geodataframe?

Comment: Does the error occur when you create the GeoDataFrame, or afterwards when you try to save it as a shapefile? And are you creating the GeoDataFrame in the same way as in your original post (the code snippet starting with `mypoly = []`)?

Comment: So I actually was able to output a shapefile that is in the correct location of the globe, has the correct CRS, and has the correct extent; but it's slightly offset from "correct". I believe this is due to me assigning an incorrect origin to the shapefile. My question now is: can I edit a `rasterio.Affine`? Printing `out_trans` gives me 6 values: the resolution in the x and y, the xy origin, and two 0's. Can I edit those values individually?